# Issue with downloading and executing a file: Python Windows 64bit

Tags: python, windows, file, permissions, 32bit-64bit

I meet a weird error when downloading and executing a file in Windows 64 with the below code. The error is that I always get the access denied. Note that this code works fine in Linux and when I use Window Explorer to manually set full permissions to the file, I can execute it (I don't know why as my code already sets full permissions to the file).

```
#open url
u = urllib2.urlopen(download_url)

#create and write to a local file
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    block_sz = 8192
    while True:
        buffer = u.read(block_sz)
        if not buffer:
            break
        f.write(buffer)

#set full permission to the file
os.chmod(filename, stat.S_IRWXU | stat.S_IRWXG | stat.S_IRWXO)
os.system(filename)
```

Comment: Note that this issue only happens in Windows 64-bit. There is no issue when running the code in Windows 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chmod), `os.chmod` can only set change read-only permissions on Windows systems.

Comment: My question is actually how to make the file executable? It is not important if the file is read-only or not as long as it is executable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue was caused by my puppet configuration, not python as there is a problem in setting up the permission in the parent directory.